# Object sizes increase after passing them to functions

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection, data.table

I am making some plots from large datasets. In this code the sizes of the resultant required plot objects are very small, but the increased usage of memory is much more than that.

My findings so far, is that the increase in memory usage seems to be due to a few objects. In particular, the value of the object `tab_ind` does not change after the graph plotting process (checked using the `identical()` function), but its size increases significantly after the process (checked using the `object.size()` function). The only thing I do with `tab_ind` during the process, is passing it to functions as arguments.

---

**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

The size of simulation can be controlled by varying `N`. At the end of the run, the change in sizes and check for identicality of `tab_ind` are printed.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 6000

set.seed(runif(1, 0, .Machine$integer.max) %>% ceiling)

logit <- function(x) {return(log(x/(1-x)))}
invLogit <- function(x) {return(exp(x)/(1+exp(x)))}

tab_dat <- data.table(datasetID = seq(N), MIX_MIN_SUCCESS = sample(c(0, 1), N, replace = T), MIX_ALL = sample(c(0, 1), N, replace = T))
tab_dat[MIX_MIN_SUCCESS == 0, MIX_ALL := 0]
n <- sample(20:300, N, replace = T)
tab_ind <- data.table(
  datasetID = rep(seq(N), times = n),
  SIM_ADJ_PP1 = runif(sum(n), 0.00001, 0.99999),
  MIX_ADJ_PP1 = runif(sum(n), 0.00001, 0.99999)
)
tab_ind[, c("SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1", "MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1") := list(logit(SIM_ADJ_PP1), logit(MIX_ADJ_PP1))]

checkMem_gc <- function(status) {
  print(status)
  print(memory.size())
  gc()
  print(memory.size())
} 

## Individual bins for x and y
tab_by_bin_idxy <- function(dt, x, y, xNItv, yNItv, by = "quantile") {
  #Binning
  if (by == "even") {
    checkMem_gc("start x-y breaks")
    checkMem_gc("start x breaks")
    minN = dt[, min(get(x), na.rm = T)]
    checkMem_gc("after x min")
    maxN = dt[, max(get(x), na.rm = T)]
    checkMem_gc("after x max")
    xBreaks = seq(minN, maxN, length.out = xNItv + 1)
    checkMem_gc("after seq")
    checkMem_gc("after x breaks")
    yBreaks = dt[, seq(min(get(y), na.rm = T), max(get(y), na.rm = T), length.out = yNItv + 1)]
    checkMem_gc("after y breaks")
  } else if (by == "quantile") {
    xBreaks = dt[, quantile(get(x), seq(0, 1, length.out = xNItv + 1), names = F)]
    yBreaks = dt[, quantile(get(y), seq(0, 1, length.out = yNItv + 1), names = F)]
  } else {stop("type of 'by' not support")}
  checkMem_gc("after x-y breaks")
  xbinCode = dt[, .bincode(get(x), breaks = xBreaks, include.lowest = T)]
  checkMem_gc("after x binCode")
  xbinMid = sapply(seq(xNItv), function(i) {return(mean(xBreaks[c(i, i+1)]))})[xbinCode]
  checkMem_gc("after x binMid")
  ybinCode = dt[, .bincode(get(y), breaks = yBreaks, include.lowest = T)]
  checkMem_gc("after y binCode")
  ybinMid = sapply(seq(yNItv), function(i) {return(mean(yBreaks[c(i, i+1)]))})[ybinCode]
  checkMem_gc("after y binMid")
  #Creating table
  tab_match = CJ(xbinCode = seq(xNItv), ybinCode = seq(yNItv))
  checkMem_gc("after tab match")
  tab_plot = data.table(xbinCode, xbinMid, ybinCode, ybinMid)[
    tab_match, .(xbinMid = xbinMid[1], ybinMid = ybinMid[1], N = .N), keyby = .EACHI, on = c("xbinCode", "ybinCode")
    ]
  checkMem_gc("after tab plot")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "xbinCode"] = paste0(x, "_binCode")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "xbinMid"] = paste0(x, "_binMid")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "ybinCode"] = paste0(y, "_binCode")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "ybinMid"] = paste0(y, "_binMid")
  checkMem_gc("after col name")
  rm(list = c("xBreaks", "yBreaks", "xbinCode", "ybinCode", "xbinMid", "ybinMid", "tab_match"))
  checkMem_gc("after rm")
  #Returning table
  return(tab_plot)
}

tab_by_obin_x_str_y <- function(dt, x, y, width, Nbin, by = "even") {
  #Binning
  if (by == "even") {
    xLLim = dt[, seq(min(get(x), na.rm = T), max(get(x), na.rm = T) - width, length.out = Nbin)]
    xULim = dt[, seq(min(get(x), na.rm = T) + width, max(get(x), na.rm = T), length.out = Nbin)]
  } else if (by == "quantile") {
    xLLim = dt[, quantile(get(x), seq(0, 1 - width, length.out = Nbin), names = F)]
    xULim = dt[, quantile(get(x), seq(width, 1, length.out = Nbin), names = F)]
  } else {stop("type of 'by' not support")}
  xbinMid = (xLLim + xULim) / 2
  #summarizing y
  tab_out <- sapply(seq(Nbin), function(i) {
    dt[get(x) >= xLLim[i] & get(x) <= xULim[i], c(mean(get(y), na.rm = T), sd(get(y), na.rm = T),
                                                  quantile(get(y), c(0.025, 0.975), names = F))]
  }) %>% t %>% as.data.table %>% set_colnames(., c("mean", "sd", ".025p", ".975p")) %>%
    cbind(data.table(binCode = seq(Nbin), xLLim, xbinMid, xULim), .)
  tab_out[, c("mean_plus_1sd", "mean_minus_1sd") := list(mean + sd, mean - sd)]
  return(tab_out)
}

plotEnv <- new.env()
backupEnv <- new.env()

gc()
gc()
checkMem_gc("Starting memory size checking")
start.mem.size <- memory.size()
start_ObjSizes <- sapply(ls(), function(x) {object.size(get(x))})
start_tab_ind <- tab_ind
start_tab_ind_size <- object.size(tab_ind)
dummyEnv <- new.env()
with(dummyEnv, {
  ## Set function for analyses against SIM_PP1
  fcn_SIM_PP1 <- function(dt, newTab = T) {
    dat_prob = tab_by_bin_idxy(dt, x = "SIM_ADJ_PP1", y = "MIX_ADJ_PP1", xNItv = 50, yNItv = 50, by = "even")
    checkMem_gc("after tab prob")
    dat_logit = tab_by_bin_idxy(dt, x = "SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1", y = "MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1",
                                xNItv = 50, yNItv = 50, by = "even")
    checkMem_gc("after tab logit")

    if ((!newTab) && exists("summarytab_logit_SIM_ADJ_PP1", where = backupEnv) && 
        exists("summarytab_prob_SIM_ADJ_PP1", where = backupEnv)) {
      summarytab_logit = get("summarytab_logit_SIM_ADJ_PP1", envir = backupEnv)
      summarytab_prob = get("summarytab_prob_SIM_ADJ_PP1", envir = backupEnv)
    } else {
      summarytab_logit = tab_by_obin_x_str_y(dt, x = "SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1", y = "MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1",
                                             width = 0.05, Nbin = 1000, by = "even") 
      summarytab_prob = summarytab_logit[, .(
        binCode, invLogit(xLLim), invLogit(xbinMid), invLogit(xULim), invLogit(mean), sd,
        invLogit(`.025p`), invLogit(`.975p`), invLogit(mean_plus_1sd), invLogit(mean_minus_1sd)
      )] %>% set_colnames(colnames(summarytab_logit))
      assign("summarytab_logit_SIM_ADJ_PP1", summarytab_logit, envir = backupEnv)
      assign("summarytab_prob_SIM_ADJ_PP1", summarytab_prob, envir = backupEnv)
    }
    checkMem_gc("after summary tab")

    plot_prob <- ggplot(dat_prob, aes(x = SIM_ADJ_PP1_binMid)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dotted") +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dotted") +
      geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, size = 1.5, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_point(aes(y = MIX_ADJ_PP1_binMid, size = N), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = T) +
      geom_line(data = summarytab_prob, aes(x = xbinMid, y = mean), size = 1.25, color = "black", na.rm = T) +
      geom_line(data = summarytab_prob, aes(x = xbinMid, y = mean_plus_1sd), size = 1.25, color = "blue", na.rm = T, linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_line(data = summarytab_prob, aes(x = xbinMid, y = mean_minus_1sd), size = 1.25, color = "blue", na.rm = T, linetype = "dashed") +
      scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5, 5)) +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "Simulated PP", breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                         labels = c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated PP", limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                         labels = c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 16))

    checkMem_gc("after plot prob")
    rm(dat_prob)
    rm(summarytab_prob)
    checkMem_gc("after removing dat_prob and summary_prob")

    plot_logit <- ggplot(dat_logit, aes(x = SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1_binMid)) +
      geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, size = 1.5, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_point(aes(y = MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1_binMid, size = N), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = T) +
      geom_line(data = summarytab_logit, aes(x = xbinMid, y = mean), size = 1.25, color = "black", na.rm = T) +
      geom_line(data = summarytab_logit, aes(x = xbinMid, y = mean_plus_1sd), size = 1.25, color = "blue", na.rm = T, linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_line(data = summarytab_logit, aes(x = xbinMid, y = mean_minus_1sd), size = 1.25, color = "blue", na.rm = T, linetype = "dashed") +
      scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5, 5)) +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "Simulated LOGIT PP1",
                         breaks = c(0.00001, 0.001, 0.05, 0.5, 0.95, 0.999, 0.99999) %>% logit,
                         labels = c("0.001%", "0.1%", "5%", "50%", "95%", "99.9%", "99.999%")) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated LOGIT PP1", limits = c(-12, 12),
                         breaks = c(0.00001, 0.001, 0.05, 0.5, 0.95, 0.999, 0.99999) %>% logit,
                         labels = c("0.001%", "0.1%", "5%", "50%", "95%", "99.9%", "99.999%")) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 16))

    checkMem_gc("after plot logit")
    rm(summarytab_logit)
    rm(dat_logit)
    checkMem_gc("after removing dat_logit and summary_logit")

    return(list(plot_prob, plot_logit))
  }

  checkMem_gc("after defining function")

  ## Tabling

  tab_stat <- tab_ind[, c("MIX_MIN_SUCCESS", "MIX_ALL") := list(
    tab_dat[tab_ind[, datasetID], MIX_MIN_SUCCESS],
    tab_dat[tab_ind[, datasetID], MIX_ALL]
  )]
  checkMem_gc("after new tab_stat")

  tab_stat_MIN_SUCCESS <- tab_stat[MIX_MIN_SUCCESS == 1]
  checkMem_gc("after new new tab_stat_MIN_SUCCESS")

  tab_stat_MIX_ALL <- tab_stat[MIX_ALL == 1]
  checkMem_gc("after new tab_stat_MIX_ALL")

  # Generating ggplot objects
  print("--- start lst full ---")
  lst_full <- fcn_SIM_PP1(tab_stat, newTab = F)
  checkMem_gc("after lst full")
  rm(tab_stat)
  checkMem_gc("after rm tab_stat")

  print("--- start lst MIN_SUCCESS ---")
  lst_MIN_SUCCESS <- fcn_SIM_PP1(tab_stat_MIN_SUCCESS, newTab = F)
  checkMem_gc("after lst MIN_SUCCESS")
  rm(tab_stat_MIN_SUCCESS)
  checkMem_gc("after rm tab_MIN_SUCCESS")

  print("--- start lst MIX_ALL ---")
  lst_MIX_ALL <- fcn_SIM_PP1(tab_stat_MIX_ALL, newTab = F)
  checkMem_gc("after lst MIX_ALL")
  rm(tab_stat_MIX_ALL)
  checkMem_gc("after rm tab_stat_MIX_ALL")

  ## Start plotting
  print("--- Start plotting ---")
  assign("full_sp_MIX_ADJ_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_PP1", lst_full[[1]], envir = plotEnv)
  checkMem_gc("after assign1")
  assign("full_sp_MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1", lst_full[[2]], envir = plotEnv)
  checkMem_gc("after assign2")
  rm(lst_full)
  checkMem_gc("after removing lst_full")
  assign("MIN_SUCCESS_sp_MIX_ADJ_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_PP1", lst_MIN_SUCCESS[[1]], envir = plotEnv)
  checkMem_gc("after assign3")
  assign("MIN_SUCCESS_sp_MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1", lst_MIN_SUCCESS[[2]], envir = plotEnv)
  checkMem_gc("after assign4")
  rm(lst_MIN_SUCCESS)
  checkMem_gc("after removing lst_MIN_SUCCESS")
  assign("MIX_ALL_sp_MIX_ADJ_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_PP1", lst_MIX_ALL[[1]], envir = plotEnv)
  checkMem_gc("after assign5")
  assign("MIX_ALL_sp_MIX_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_LOGIT_PP1", lst_MIX_ALL[[2]], envir = plotEnv)
  checkMem_gc("after assign6")
  rm(lst_MIX_ALL)
  checkMem_gc("after removing lst_MIX_ALL")
})

checkMem_gc("--- Finishing ---")
rm(dummyEnv)
gc()
checkMem_gc("After clean up")
final.mem.size <- memory.size()
end_ObjSizes <- sapply(ls(), function(x) {object.size(get(x))})
print("")
print("")
print("--- The sizes of all objects (under .GlobalEnv) BEFORE the graph plotting process ---")
print("--- (Before the process starts, all existing objects are stored under .GlobalEnv) ---")
print(start_ObjSizes)
print("")
print("--- The sizes of all objects (under .GlobalEnv) AFTER the graph plotting process ---")
print(end_ObjSizes)
print("--- I have not altered any existing objects under .GlobalEnv during the process, I only passed them to functions. And yet their sizes increase! ---")
print("--- Let's look at the object tab_ind, which shows the largest inflation in object size ---")
print("--- This is the size of tab_ind BEFORE the process: ---")
print(start_tab_ind_size)
print("--- This is the size of tab_ind AFTER the process: ---")
print(object.size(tab_ind))
print("--- But they are identical (checked using the function identical())! ---")
print(identical(start_tab_ind, tab_ind))
print("")
```

---

**UPDATED REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

This is an updated, simpler reproducible example. The latest finding is that to make a copy of `data.table` object, `<- data.table::copy()` should be used instead of `<-`. The latter only creates a pointer to the same value (i.e. by reference). Altering the value of the new pointer would changes the object size of the original pointer, that was why object size inflated when I made change to the new pointer. Although I am not sure if it is the only source of memory usage inflation.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 6000

set.seed(runif(1, 0, .Machine$integer.max) %>% ceiling)

logit <- function(x) {return(log(x/(1-x)))}
invLogit <- function(x) {return(exp(x)/(1+exp(x)))}

tab_dat <- data.table(datasetID = seq(N), MIX_MIN_SUCCESS = sample(c(0, 1), N, replace = T), MIX_ALL = sample(c(0, 1), N, replace = T))
tab_dat[MIX_MIN_SUCCESS == 0, MIX_ALL := 0]
n <- sample(20:300, N, replace = T)
tab_ind <- data.table(
  datasetID = rep(seq(N), times = n),
  SIM_ADJ_PP1 = runif(sum(n), 0.00001, 0.99999),
  MIX_ADJ_PP1 = runif(sum(n), 0.00001, 0.99999)
)

## Individual bins for x and y
tab_by_bin_idxy <- function(dt, x, y, xNItv, yNItv, by = "quantile") {
  #Binning
  if (by == "even") {
    minN = dt[, min(get(x), na.rm = T)]
    maxN = dt[, max(get(x), na.rm = T)]
    xBreaks = seq(minN, maxN, length.out = xNItv + 1)
    yBreaks = dt[, seq(min(get(y), na.rm = T), max(get(y), na.rm = T), length.out = yNItv + 1)]
  } else if (by == "quantile") {
    xBreaks = dt[, quantile(get(x), seq(0, 1, length.out = xNItv + 1), names = F)]
    yBreaks = dt[, quantile(get(y), seq(0, 1, length.out = yNItv + 1), names = F)]
  }
  xbinCode = dt[, .bincode(get(x), breaks = xBreaks, include.lowest = T)]
  xbinMid = sapply(seq(xNItv), function(i) {return(mean(xBreaks[c(i, i+1)]))})[xbinCode]
  ybinCode = dt[, .bincode(get(y), breaks = yBreaks, include.lowest = T)]
  ybinMid = sapply(seq(yNItv), function(i) {return(mean(yBreaks[c(i, i+1)]))})[ybinCode]
  #Creating table
  tab_match = CJ(xbinCode = seq(xNItv), ybinCode = seq(yNItv))
  tab_plot = data.table(xbinCode, xbinMid, ybinCode, ybinMid)[
    tab_match, .(xbinMid = xbinMid[1], ybinMid = ybinMid[1], N = .N), keyby = .EACHI, on = c("xbinCode", "ybinCode")
    ]
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "xbinCode"] = paste0(x, "_binCode")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "xbinMid"] = paste0(x, "_binMid")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "ybinCode"] = paste0(y, "_binCode")
  colnames(tab_plot)[colnames(tab_plot) == "ybinMid"] = paste0(y, "_binMid")
  rm(list = c("xBreaks", "yBreaks", "xbinCode", "ybinCode", "xbinMid", "ybinMid", "tab_match"))
  #Returning table
  return(tab_plot)
}

plotEnv <- new.env()
backupEnv <- new.env()

gc()
gc(verbose = T)
start.mem.size <- memory.size()
start_ObjSizes <- sapply(ls(), function(x) {object.size(get(x))})
start_tab_ind <- copy(tab_ind)
start_tab_ind_size <- object.size(tab_ind)
dummyEnv <- new.env()
with(dummyEnv, {
  ## Set function for analyses against SIM_PP1
  fcn_SIM_PP1 <- function(dt, newTab = T) {
    dat_prob = tab_by_bin_idxy(dt, x = "SIM_ADJ_PP1", y = "MIX_ADJ_PP1", xNItv = 50, yNItv = 50, by = "even")

    plot_prob <- ggplot(dat_prob, aes(x = SIM_ADJ_PP1_binMid)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dotted") +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dotted") +
      geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, size = 1.5, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_point(aes(y = MIX_ADJ_PP1_binMid, size = N), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = T) +
      scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5, 5)) +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "Simulated PP", breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                         labels = c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated PP", limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                         labels = c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 16))

    return(plot_prob)
  }

  ## Tabling
  tab_stat <- copy(tab_ind)
  tab_stat <- tab_stat[, c("MIX_MIN_SUCCESS", "MIX_ALL") := list(
    tab_dat[tab_stat[, datasetID], MIX_MIN_SUCCESS],
    tab_dat[tab_stat[, datasetID], MIX_ALL]
  )]

  tab_stat_MIN_SUCCESS <- tab_stat[MIX_MIN_SUCCESS == 1]

  tab_stat_MIX_ALL <- tab_stat[MIX_ALL == 1]

  # Generating ggplot objects
  lst_full <- fcn_SIM_PP1(tab_stat, newTab = F)
  lst_MIN_SUCCESS <- fcn_SIM_PP1(tab_stat_MIN_SUCCESS, newTab = F)
  lst_MIX_ALL <- fcn_SIM_PP1(tab_stat_MIX_ALL, newTab = F)

  ## Start plotting
  assign("full_sp_MIX_ADJ_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_PP1", lst_full, envir = plotEnv)
  assign("MIN_SUCCESS_sp_MIX_ADJ_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_PP1", lst_MIN_SUCCESS, envir = plotEnv)
  assign("MIX_ALL_sp_MIX_ADJ_PP1_vs_SIM_ADJ_PP1", lst_MIX_ALL, envir = plotEnv)
})

rm(dummyEnv)
rm(start_tab_ind)
gc(verbose = T)
final.mem.size <- memory.size()
end_ObjSizes <- sapply(ls(), function(x) {object.size(get(x))})
```

---

My `sessionInfo()` when running the above example:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
  [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Hong Kong SAR.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Hong Kong SAR.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Hong Kong SAR.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_Hong Kong SAR.1252    

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] ggplot2_2.2.1     magrittr_1.5      data.table_1.11.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     compiler_3.5.0   lazyeval_0.2.1   plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.5.0      pillar_1.2.3     gtable_0.2.0    
[9] tibble_1.4.2     yaml_2.1.19      Rcpp_0.12.18     grid_3.5.0       rlang_0.2.1      munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Generally, you should never trigger `gc` manually. Note that manual calls to `gc` can interfere with internal optimizations such as the JIT compiler. Can you please explain what your actual problem is? Why do you need to release memory to the OS?

Comment: I am not trying to release memory to the OS. I am simply running out of memory to use in R. In that case I needed to check if it is my necessary object being too large, or there are some spaces occupied by whatever unnecessary. My actual problem is if I run the same code (as in the reproducible example) with my full datasets, I encounter the `cannot allocate vector of size ...` error in R, which is the error that you get when you run out of memory for R to use. I have already requested a lot of memory in R using `memory.limit()`. I cannot push this limit further.

Comment: Sorry, I won't look into a dropbox for a reproducible example. You are supposed to provide one *in the question*  (also because of link rot). Since you are apparently running out of memory during a `merge` I wonder if you might be doing a (unintended) cartesian join. I've had that happen to me.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, I have already removed `merge` (First point under findings). The results are still not satisfactory (other points under findings). I will try to find a way to include an example in the question. It is not easy...

Comment: To post a reproducible example small enough to fit in the question, I need `memory.size()` to be able to display the memory usage with precision up to the order of kb or b. However `memory.size()` defaults to display the usage in mb with precision up to only 1~2 decimal places. If the precision cannot be improved, a reproducible example small enough to fit in the question cannot tell my problem... Any suggestion for me?

Comment: Can't you just simulate data and let people adjust the size until they can reproduce your error message?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have amended the reproducible example.

Comment: Can you share your `sessionInfo()` information and your machines available memory?

Comment: Sorry, your example is too long for me to investigate. Two remarks: after setting `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)` I see many messages `'(m)get' found in j. ansvars being set to all columns. Use .SDcols or a single j=eval(macro) instead. Both will detect the columns used which is important for efficiency.` Also, I suggest checking the `truelength` of the data.table. I'd also investigate if your code triggers any deep copies.

Comment: You are off to a great start with a complete and reproducible example. To extend on Roland's point, you should try and make your example more **Minimal** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you show your problem in many different ways, but it would be easier to debug the issue if you can reproduce in less calls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My sense is you need to increase the `--min-vsize=`. Why? The error `cannot allocate vector of size ...` implies you need to increase `--min-vsize=`.

#### R Command Line Invocation:

`R --min-vsize=400M`

#### RStudio Invocation

Create or add an entry to your `.Renviron` file.

`R_VSIZE=400M`

Ref: Friendly R Startup Configuration

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html

### Key Questions:

- Are you running a 64bit OS? [Yes/No]
- Are you running a 64bit version of R? [Yes/No]

if you answer "No" to either of these questions I'd recommend you upgrade.

### **Background**

The reality here is that if you need to increase the minimum vsize, you likely want to look at your code for assignment gotchas. In most cases, you'll find that you are duplicating data via copy assignment.

For more information on R Gotcha's I highly recommend you read:

- Patrick Burns online book [R Inferno](http://burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

#### The detail behind it all.

R maintains separate areas for fixed and variable sized objects. The first of these is allocated as an array of cons cells (Lisp programmers will know what they are, others may think of them as the building blocks of the language itself, parse trees, etc.), and the second are thrown on a heap of ‘Vcells’ of 8 bytes each. Each cons cell occupies 28 bytes on a 32-bit build of R, (usually) 56 bytes on a 64-bit build.

The default values are (currently) an initial setting of 350k cons cells and 6Mb of vector heap. Note that the areas are not actually allocated initially: rather these values are the sizes for triggering garbage collection. These values can be set by the command line options `--min-nsize` and `--min-vsize` (or if they are not used, the environment variables `R_NSIZE` and `R_VSIZE`) when R is started. Thereafter R will grow or shrink the areas depending on usage, never decreasing below the initial values. The maximal vector heap size can be set with the environment variable `R_MAX_VSIZE`.

How much time R spends in the garbage collector will depend on these initial settings and on the trade-off the memory manager makes, when memory fills up, between collecting garbage to free up unused memory and growing these areas. The strategy used for growth can be specified by setting the environment variable R_GC_MEM_GROW to an integer value between 0 and 3. This variable is read at start-up. Higher values grow the heap more aggressively, thus reducing garbage collection time but using more memory.

Ref:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/Memory

### Windows

The address-space limit is 2Gb under 32-bit Windows unless the OS's default has been changed to allow more (up to 3Gb). See https://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/server/PAE/PAEmem.mspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473(VS.85).aspx. Under most 64-bit versions of Windows the limit for a 32-bit build of R is 4Gb: for the oldest ones it is 2Gb. The limit for a 64-bit build of R (imposed by the OS) is 8Tb.

It is not normally possible to allocate as much as 2Gb to a single vector in a 32-bit build of R even on 64-bit Windows because of preallocations by Windows in the middle of the address space.

Under Windows, R imposes limits on the total memory allocation available to a single session as the OS provides no way to do so: see memory.size and memory.limit.

Comment: Let me supplement my `sessionInfo()` to the question.

Comment: I know I can start an R session through command prompt with `--min-vsize` setting like `R --min-vsize=400M`, but I am struggling with doing the same when using Rstudio... Still looking for the way... Any help?

Comment: @MatthewHui I believe you can set the environment variable R_VSIZE prior to launching RStudio.

Comment: I believe that if I open Rstudio and type Sys.getenv("R_VSIZE") and see [1] "400M", that means I am doing the setting correctly? After making this setting, I tried to rerun the reproducible example above, but the inflation in memory is still disproportionately larger than the size of the new objects. So, maybe there is some other problems than memory limit / VSIZE that is causing the inflation? I have edited the question to be more specific...

Comment: Lets check a few things. If you run 'R --min-vsize=400M' does you code complete correctly? If "yes" then the problem is how to do this via RStudio. Happy to help on that point but just clarifying situation first :-)

Comment: The code completed correctly.
I think that I just found a probable cause of the problem... In my case, I thought I had made a copy of the large `tab_ind` object by `<-`, which I deleted after use. The truth is, I did not make a copy. `data.table` handles `<-` by reference. Therefore, when I assigned new columns using `:=`, I am actually altering the value that the original pointer `tab_ind` represents. In my latest trial, I created a copy using `<- data.table::copy()`, now the object sizes do not inflate! Though, I am not quite sure if it is the only cause.

Comment: @MatthewHui I updated the answer to reflect our conversation. See comment on .REnviron.